# Simple React counter not working, also can't console.log useState variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm fairly new to React (only started learning a month ago) and I'm trying to get a simple counter to show on the page, but it only ever updates once. Also, whenever I `console.log()` useState variables, they're always empty, but since I added them to output on the page, I can see that they're updating, but I still can't console.log the values? What gives? I must be doing something wrong but I can't see to figure out why.

Here's a demo of the "problem" in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jqwidgets-react-testing-library-mxo8k).

this is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css";
import JqxInput from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxinput";

const MyForm2: React.FC = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const onEmailChange = (e?: any) => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setEmail(e.args.value);
    console.log('You typed: ' + e.args.value);
    console.log("name: " + name + ", email: " + email);
  };

  const onNameChange = (e?: any) => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setName(e.args.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Name:{" "}
      <JqxInput value={name} onChange={(e: any) => setName(e.args.value)} />
      Email: <JqxInput value={email} onChange={onEmailChange} />
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <p>email: {email}</p>
      <p>name: {name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyForm2;
```

Thanks. I look forward to finding out my spectacular mistake :-)

Comment: Regarding the inability to console.log, I now realise that this is because it's a functional component. The function is called each and every time the component needs to update, so it's a fresh call each time (unlike a class; that would also explain why the useState variables are actually constants, yet can seemingly be updated 'all the time'). This is how I can use console.log in a React.FC (but not in my onWhateverChange method):

useEffect(() => console.log('count = ' + count));

Comment: `useEffect()` still doesnt work for me adding a console.log. I'm baffled as to why React is so contrived that it cannot achieve in a simple way something that Angular and Vue.js does for basics. The console.log, in any competent framework, would be allowed to be used anywhere in a component where there is a lifecycle hook or a function. React would do best to just standardize one component. It's like this framework doesnt know what it wants and so it just tries a bunch of different incomplete things, leading to a confused and incomplete framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the next state is depended on the previous state you should pass a function updater as an argument to `setState`. So change to this:

```
setCount((count) => count + 1)
```

Comment: This results in the count incrementing by 2 each time. I've checked my console to confirm that the event isn't being called twice (resulting in a double-up of messages). If I add 0.5 each time, it works the way I want, but I don't understand why I can't just add one 

Comment: Actually, the event *is* being called twice. With the console open on Codesandbox you don't get to see the doubled-up messages but with it closed, you can see the number in the round blue circle increment twice each time.

Answer (score 1):

Duo to [Javascript Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), `onNameChange` scope closes upon `count` variable:

```js
const MyForm2: React.FC = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const onEmailChange = (e?: any) => {
    setCount(prev => prev + 1);           // <-- no closure, use previous state
                                          // Render as expected.
    setEmail(e.args.value);
  };

  const onNameChange = (e?: any) => {
    setCount(count + 1);                  // <-- `count` always 0;
                                          // Will always redner the value '1'.
    setName(e.args.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Name: <JqxInput value={name} onChange={onNameChange} />
      Email: <JqxInput value={email} onChange={onEmailChange} />
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Q-56914083-Closures]